# Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'InkWell'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   InkWell tile({String? date}) {
return InkWell(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 40,
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(
        date?? 'Null',
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I have a tappable List Tile with the title variable 'date' which I will assign later, so I am going to pass this to another file as shown now:

```
randomParameter: anotherFile(tile()), // might be an error idk
```

inside file where tile widget will be imported to:

```
anotherFile(required InkWell tile){
const String today = 'Today';
        const String tmrw = 'Tomorrow';
        const String week = 'Next Week';
    ExpansionTile(children: [tile(date: today), tile(date: tmrw), tile(date: week)]) };////Error!
```

> Error: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be
> invoked. The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'InkWell'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `anotherFile(required InkWell tile){` to `anotherFile(required InkWell Function(string) tile){`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that another file doesnt evaluate to a function

For example a function will look like

```
void someFunction()
{
}
```

In this case you are adding an expansion tile to a parameter which i assume you are trying to return an ExpansionTile

If you wish to return a widget then you can try writing it like

```dart
Widget anotherFile(required InkWell tile){
 return ExpansionTile();
}
```

Now this method will return a wodget of type expansion tile

Comment: Sorry but I meant something else. I created a widget in a file with a parameter, and I want to pass this widget to another file and use inside expansion tile's children.